# "Incoming e-mail settings" hidden from custom document library

Tags: document-library, visual-studio, incoming-email

Very simple set-up:

Visual Studio --> Add New Item --> List Definition. Type: *Document Library*. Besides that - no changes. Deploy.

Result:
[image]

As you can see: No "configure incoming e-mail settings" link.

When I create a document library the regular way (e.g. Site Actions --> New Document Library) I get the wanted result:
[image]

How to I get the **"Incoming e-mail settings"** link on a document library deployed via Visual Studio?

---

**EDIT** (thanks to Falak):
The **solution** is to add (even if only a dummy) `SPEmailEventreceiver` to the list. So if you do this:

```
public class MyMailEventReceiver : SPEmailEventReceiver
{
    public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, string receiverData)
    {
        base.EmailReceived(list, emailMessage, receiverData);
    }
}
```

and the elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="xyz"> <!-- add the correct template id here -->
      <Receiver>
        <Name>MyMailEventReceiver</Name>
        <Type>EmailReceived</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>myAssembly.MyMailEventReceiver</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Voilá, I have the incoming e-mail settings link in the document library settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SharePoint only shows Incoming Email settings link for **OOTB** lists of type Announcements, Event, Document Library, Picture Library, XML Form, Discussion Board, Posts.

So, if you create a custom list, you need to create a custom email event handler and attach to your list and then Incoming Email settings link will be available.

More info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/f8d57aba-2a0e-41a1-a280-2e022f5604e3

Comment: Great documentation on the MS side... I added the solution above for future reference.